# git - how to create an unreachable commit for git prune?

Tags: git

I am writing educational material for git and I need to demonstrate `git prune` removing a "detached object". I thought I could put a commit in detached state by using `git reset` to detach it from the branch history.

This will trigger `git checkout` to see the commit as detached, however `git prune` will not care about it.

My current detached commit simulation is setup like the following:

```
~ $ mkdir git-prune-demo
~ $ cd git-prune-demo/
~/git-prune-demo $ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/kev/Dropbox/git-prune-demo/.git/
~/git-prune-demo $ echo "hello git prune" > hello.txt
~/git-prune-demo $ git add hello.txt
~/git-prune-demo $ git commit -am "added hello.txt"
[master (root-commit) 994b122] added hello.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt
~/git-prune-demo $ echo "this is second line txt" >> hello.txt
~/git-prune-demo $ git commit -am "added another line to hello.txt"
[master 5178bec] added another line to hello.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/git-prune-demo $ git reset --hard 994b122045cf4bf0b97139231b4dd52ea2643c7e
HEAD is now at 994b122 added hello.txt
~/git-prune-demo $ git prune -n
~/git-prune-demo $ nothing
```

Yes, I understand `git prune` is generally not used as a standalone command and is essentially a child to `git gc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You will need to run `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now` first, then `git prune --expire now`.  Even then, things may go wrong, though for this particular simple example, that's likely to suffice.

#### Long

> I am writing educational material for git and I need to demonstrate git prune removing a detached commit.

That's not what `git prune` *does*, though.  What it does can *produce this effect*, but only under particular conditions.  Importantly, *detached commit* is not a well defined phrase in Git: Git has a definition for a *detached HEAD*—we'll come back to this in a moment—but commits themselves are either *reachable* or *unreachable*.  I think you mean to talk about unreachable commits, here.

Importantly, `git prune` deals with *objects*, which are more general than commits.  Git has four types of objects: commits, trees, blobs, and annotated tags.  Git's `git prune` can remove *any* unreachable object, provided several other conditions are met.  Before we get there, though, let's look at a few more items.

#### Correcting misapprehensions

> I thought I could put a commit in detached state by using `git reset` to detach it from the branch history.

A commit—or any other Git object—is, by definition, reachable if there is some external name that either names the commit (or object) itself directly, or that names some other object by which we can reach the given commit.  (For more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)  Using `git reset`, we can make commits that were reachable only through the current branch name, become unreachable.  For instance, if commit `a123456...` is reachable only through the current branch name—i.e., not through any other branch name, nor through any tag name or other non-branch-name reference—then using `git reset` to adjust the current branch so that it excludes `a123456...` makes that commit unreachable.

> This will trigger `git checkout` to see the commit as detached ...

I think here you're talking about what Git calls a detached HEAD.

A detached HEAD simply means that Git's special HEAD reference, stored as a file named `.git/HEAD`, contains the raw hash ID of a commit.  The opposite condition—which we can call an *attached HEAD*, since that's the obvious antonym for *detached*—occurs when `.git/HEAD` contains a branch name.  In both cases, `HEAD` refers to the current commit; when `HEAD` contains a branch name, `HEAD` also refers to the current branch name.  The way Git deals with this internally is that it has different functions and programs to resolve `HEAD` either symbolically:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

or to a hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231
```

(For the detached HEAD case, `git symbolic-ref` produces an error, since there is no branch name.)

The `git checkout` command attaches HEAD (to some specified branch name) when:

- you give it a name that is a branch name, or
- you use it to create and then attach-to a new branch name.

It detaches HEAD when:

- you give it something that does resolve to a hash ID, but not to a branch name (e.g., a raw hash ID, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`), or
- you use the `--detach` flag to force a detached HEAD even though it would have attached HEAD normally.

Detached HEAD mode does not mean that you are working with an unreachable commit.  In fact, detaching HEAD to an otherwise-unreachable commit, makes that commit suddenly reachable *because* it is now the HEAD commit.  In other words, detaching HEAD to any commit adds one more way to reach the commit, but as far as prune is concerned, the interesting question is not *how many* names reach the object in question, just whether the number is nonzero.  One name, two names, ten names, or millions of names: all of these are the same to `git prune`.  When I say *names* here, I mean more than just the reference names plus the possible detached `HEAD`, but we'll start with just these names before we add the next complication.

#### Git's object model, and references to objects

[Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) has a good description of how references make commits reachable.  It doesn't mention, though, that in general, references can specify the hash ID of *any* object, not just commits.  This is because it's concerned with branches, not just any old object, and both branch names (`refs/heads/*`) and remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/*`) are constrained to point only to commits.  It also does not go into the details of what's inside a commit, i.e., how Git stores files and file-names.  This is where tree and blob objects come in.

Each commit contains the hash ID of a single tree object.  A tree object contains a series of triple-valued items: mode, name, and hash-ID.  The mode specifies whether this tree entry is for a file, for a sub-tree, or for one of the more exotic items (symbolic links and gitlinks).  The name gives the name of the entity being represented, such as `README.txt` or `subdir` or `file.ext`.  The hash ID is generally the ID of either a blob object or another tree object: if the entry is for a file like `README.txt`, it's a blob hash, and if it's for a sub-tree like `subdir`, it's the hash ID of the subtree.

If we draw all of this out for a single commit, starting with the branch name at the right of the top-most line, we get something like this:

```
... <-  commit a1234...   <-- branchname
               |
               v
        tree 07f39...: (100644, README.txt, 531c2...); (040000, subdir, ...)
                                               |                         |
                                               v                         |
                                blob 531c2...: data for README.txt       |
                                                                         |
                                                                         v
                                                               tree ...: ...
```

Annotated tag objects are permitted to point to *any other* object (including other annotated tag objects), though most often, they just point to commit objects.  So adding annotated tags to this picture, we'd generally just see a tag reference like `refs/tags/v1.0` pointing to an annotated tag object with some hash ID, where the annotated tag object then goes on to point to, say, commit `a1234...`.  That would give that commit yet another reference.  If we have not created any tags, we won't need to worry about these, but they are important for a full picture.

As with commits, any object is referenced if there is some path leading from some external name—or for blobs, the internal references stored in Git's *index*—that leads to those objects.  The index can only refer to blobs, so when we're only interested in commits, we can ignore the index's references, but like tags, they are important for the full picture.

Anyway, in the above diagram, we can see that the name `branchname` makes commit `a1234...` reachable.  Commit `a1234...` makes tree `07f39...` reachable, which makes a blob and another sub-tree reachable, and so on.  Since these are all reachable, `git prune` definitely *won't* prune them.

Importantly, each reference name, plus the special `HEAD` name, has an optional *reflog* that stores, for that reference, *previous values* of the reference.  These saved values remain valid for some time, until they expire.  The command that Git uses to expire stale saved values is `git reflog expire`, using two different command-line options, `--expire=when` and `--expire-unreachable=when`.

If you want to show `git prune` removing an object, you'll need to make sure that the object is *completely* unreferenced.  This means you will need to remove any reflog entries that remember, directly (commits) or indirectly (trees and blobs) its hash ID.  The easy—albeit rather destructive—method of doing that is to use:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
```

(We could add `--expire=now` but we can assume that the current value of the reference does not reach the reflog value, so the `--expire-unreachable` setting is the one that will apply.)

That sets up a *necessary* condition; now it is time to get back to `git prune` itself.

#### With all that out of the way, let's get back to `git prune`

The `git prune` command deals with all four types of objects.  Its job is to remove *unreferenced* objects.  From the above, we know that we'll have to make sure the commit is unreferenced, by expiring any reflog entries that might remember it, after using a command like `git branch -f` or `git branch -D` or `git reset` to make sure that no branch names remember it either.

But now we need to know two more things about Git objects:

- they can be either *loose* or *packed*, and
- they have an age, rather like reflog entries.

An object that is *loose* is stored in a separate file in the file system.  This makes it easy for Git to manipulate it, but means that it is minimally compressed.  Git will, upon command (or automatically via `git gc`), *pack* many separate objects together into a single *pack file*.  At this point, one file in the file system contains many objects: tens, perhaps, or millions, or something in between.

The `prune` command will *never* prune a packed object, because that's too hard.  A packed object may be part of a delta-compression chain within its pack file.  So instead, `git prune` will only look at *loose* objects.  A separate program—`git repack`—will re-do the packing of objects, and can turn unreferenced packed objects back into loose objects (or discard them entirely).

In general, objects don't get packed immediately, so a recently-created object is likely to be loose.  If the object *has* been packed, though, and is now unreferenced, you will need to run `git repack` instead.

Meanwhile, as protection against competing Git processes, `git prune` *also* checks the time-stamp on loose objects.  This time stamp must be old enough to permit `git prune` to remove the object.  The reason for this is that when Git is creating *new* objects, including new commits, it will write these objects into the repository database one (or just a few) at a time.  Git has to write the deepest subtrees with their blob hashes, then write the next-layer-up trees using the subtrees and their hashes along with any blob hashes that go in those trees.  Once Git has written out all the trees and obtained the top-level tree hash to go into a new commit, only then can Git write the commit object.  Until this point, all those trees are unreferenced.  Even once the commit is written, *that's* unreferenced too, until the current branch name (or the detached `HEAD`) is updated to point to the newly-created commit.

This process takes time.  Git gives itself 14 days, by default, to complete the process.  If a `git commit` takes more than 14 days to complete, a `git prune` might remove some of its objects—but 14 days should be plenty of time.

If you know you are not running any other Git commands, you can manually override the default:

```
git prune --expire now
```

means that any unreferenced, loose objects should be deleted no matter how new they are.  So all you need to do is make sure your commit is unreferenced, then prune with a "now" expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

Prune will ordinarily not remove objects that have been reachable from any ref within the last ... I forget, month? -- it checks the local reflogs for that.  Pass `--expire now` to disable the oops protections on object removal, but if you're writing docs, do suggest that'd be a really, really bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it was the expiration. What date format is it expecting? no luck with `git prune --dry-run --expire "`date +%Y-%m-%d`"` it might expect a unix timestamp?

Comment: no luck with ```git prune --dry-run --expire "`date +%s `"``` either