# why are commits being duplicated in gitk --all?

Tags: git

In my app that has a Git repo I noticed in the `gitk --all` viewer that there are some commits with the same description and datestamp, though they have different hashes.  There are 3 pairs of duplications, all dated 2022-06-21 with paired timestamps.

[image]

Interestingly enough, in the VS Code Source Control panel, the Commits section does not display the duplicated commits -

[image]

I'm thinking the fix for this is probably to move the `state-2` tag to the commit hash for the description "Add scenario module" that's on the main branch (topmost one in screenshot) but I'm wondering why/how this happened in the first place?

Comment: Looks like someone rebased. In git, unless they're unreachable, commits are immutable.

Comment: Those are different commits. If you click on one in gitk, gitk will fill in the commit hash ID. Try clicking on two that look similar and note that the hash ID changes. So these are different commits—the hash ID is the "real name" or "true name" of the commit.

Comment: Yes, using `git log --all --pretty="format:%h %ai %ci %s" -12`  and comparing the author date and committer date, a rebase is precisely what happened.

Comment: Rebase is essentially repeated `git cherry-pick` followed by "stop using old commits, start using new-and-improved copies". If two different branch names reached the old commits before rebasing, well, now after rebase, the branch name you were on reaches the new and improved copies, and the other name still reaches the old ones.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if the commit hash which is currently tagged with `state-2` had not been tagged when the rebase occurred then the apparent duplication would not exist?

Comment: @knot22 the commits would still exist, they just wouldn't show up in the gitk or git log output. After a few weeks git would remove them for being "unreachable"

Comment: Oh, yes, because they're the old commits.  But they would be unreachable if they weren't tagged, right?  If so, then they wouldn't show in the `gitk --all` view and it would just appear as though everything were on the main branch?

Comment: _"A commit---or any other Git object---is, by definition, reachable if there is some external name that either names the commit (or object) itself directly, or that names some other object by which we can reach the given commit. (For more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)"_ - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582651/git-how-to-create-an-unreachable-commit-for-git-prune

Comment: Just delete tag `state-2` and call it a day.